# ARC and C++ in my code

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

I have a scenario where I am trying to create a generic C++ class (across platforms) that can operate on an Array . This C++ class is meant to be portable across OS's such that it can leverage the native Array support.

For example, it'll use NSArray when running on Mac OS / iOS, or an MFC array class in Windows. My goal is to make this array management class generic.

```
#ifndef __MixTest__ArrayUser__
#define __MixTest__ArrayUser__

#if defined _MAC_OS
typedef void * ARRAY_HANDLE;
//#elif defined _WINDOWS
#endif

class ArrayUser
{
public:
    ArrayUser() { }
    virtual ~ArrayUser() { }
    void assignArray(ARRAY_HANDLE handle)
    {
        m_array_handle = handle;
    }
    void UseArray();

private:
    ARRAY_HANDLE m_array_handle;
};
#endif /* defined(__MixTest__ArrayUser__) */


//  ArrayUser.cpp
//  MixTest

#include "ArrayUser.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
void ArrayUser::UseArray()
{
    NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray *) m_array_handle;

    for (NSString *str in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"Array - %@",str);
    }
}
```

Now my goal is to run this on Mac OS and I do the following in my barebones Mac OS project

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) NSArray *arrayItems;
@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include "ArrayUser.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    ArrayUser arrayUser;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(id) init
{
    if([super init] !=nil)
    {
        _arrayItems = @[@"Planes",@"Trains",@"Automobiles"];
        arrayUser.assignArray((__bridge ARRAY_HANDLE)_arrayItems);

        arrayUser.UseArray();
    }
    return self;
}
```

Questions

1. Is this transfer appropriate ?

   arrayUser.assignArray((__bridge ARRAY_HANDLE)_arrayItems);

The expectation is that _arrayItems being strong and is expected to be controlled via the AppDelegate.

2. If _arrayItems weren't defined as being strong, then what is the
       right way to bridge such that the object cannot be destroyed
       (because ArrayUser needs it ) ?
3. Should the bridging be the same irrespective of whether or not
   _arrayItems is strong or weak? The fact that ArrayUser needs it, should indicate to ARC that the object cannot be deallocated. What
   is the bridging in this case ?

Comment: I think your goals are misguided as C++'s own collection classes are more flexible that Objective-C's.

Comment: and my constraint is that I cannot use stl in any case. My question is more towards the bridging concept and ARC and not necessarily Array. Consider the Array as an example

Comment: Well in that case the thing to do is create an Objective-C++ implementation just for Apple platforms, perhaps sitting behind an pure-virtual interface class, so that it can be swapped-out for other platforms.